# Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this below query

```
SELECT Group_concat(employeename) AS name 
  FROM employee 
  WHERE Find_in_set(Find_in_set(employeeid,
         (SELECT participantsids 
            FROM schedule 
            WHERE validfrom = '2016-04-21 17:00:00' 
              AND validto = '2016-04-21 17:30:00') 
          ), '1,2');
```

Which returns me a correct value..
But now I have to check

```
SELECT participantsids 
  FROM schedule 
  WHERE validfrom <= '2016-04-21 17:00:00' 
    AND validto >= '2016-04-21 17:30:00';
```

This returns more rows, but I want to include this in my 1st query so I tried this

```
SELECT Group_concat(employeename) AS name 
  FROM employee 
  WHERE Find_in_set(Find_in_set(employeeid,
         (SELECT participantsids 
            FROM schedule 
            WHERE validfrom <= '2016-04-21 17:00:00' 
              AND validto >= '2016-04-21 17:30:00')
         ), '1,2');
```

This returns error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

I have tried using **ANY** and **In** before the subquery but it shows syntax error and my question is at what point should I correctly use them?

Comment: Correct use of ANY, IN and SOME: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Comment: It's quite difficult to guess what you're actually trying to accomplish with the nested `FIND_IN_SET()` invocations.  What does `participantids` contain?  If the answer is "a comma-separated list" then your database design needs to be discarded.  `FIND_IN_SET()` is a function that should *rarely* be used in the `WHERE` clause because it is opaque to the optimizer in most, if not all, cases, and will force a full table scan.

Answer (score 2):

You can try limit

```
 SELECT participantsids 
 FROM schedule 
 WHERE validfrom <= '2016-04-21 17:00:00' 
     AND validto >= '2016-04-21 17:30:00'
 LIMIT 1;
```

in your case i think you are using Find_in_set in an improper way you should use a set notation like this

```
  SELECT Group_concat(employeename) AS name 
  FROM employee 
  WHERE ( employeeid,
     (SELECT participantsids 
        FROM schedule 
        WHERE validfrom <= '2016-04-21 17:00:00' 
          AND validto >= '2016-04-21 17:30:00'
          LIMIT 1) =  (1,2);
```

Comment: but that will not serve my purpose

Comment: If you want only a row in subselect ... this subselect return only the firts row ... otherwise please explain me your goal ....

Comment: Anyway looking at you code seems you are using find_in_set in an improper way so i suggest you a different  query  ... i have update the answer .